# How is typecasting Connection to OracleConnection different from connection.unwrap(OracleConnection.class)

Tags: java, database, oracle, jdbc, ojdbc

How is typecasting a java.sql.Connection to OracleConnecction different from getting OracleConnection from java.sql.Connection unwrap method .

Also, If I am creating OracleConnection through connection.unwrap(OracleConnection.class) then should I close the OracleConnection in finally or java.sql.Connection in finally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is somewhat subtle but meaningful.

Typecasting will fail with `ClassCastException` if the actual implementation object is incompatible with the declared class.  I.e. if the implementation is not an `OracleConnection` and you try to typecast it you'll get the exception.

Using `unwrap(Class clazz)` will attempt to find an object of the specified type and return that, failing with a `SQLException` instead if that's not possible.  The benefit of using the `Wrapper` interface methods is that you can check in advance if the `unwrap` will succeed, with the `isWrapperFor` method.

Comment: OK. What about closing the connection. Oracle connection is made through unwrap then should I close the original connection or unwrapped oracleconnection

Comment: Since the original one still wraps the `OracleConnection` I would think you'd want to close the original.  I.e. unwrap to get access to vendor specific methods but put the original in your try-with-resources statement.

Comment: @NitinGupta Unwrapping doesn't 'make' an Oracle connection, it only returns the already existing instance. Closing this unwrapped instance might be a bad thing (consider a pooled connection that allows you to unwrap, closing the unwrapped connection would be 'bad').

Comment: In addition, unwrapping can be richer than just casting, as it could also return objects **contained** inside the connection/statement/result set object.